# Ubuntu software for writing ISO image to SD card?

Tags: 14.04, iso, sd-card, burning, disk-image

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried a few different methods of writing an .ISO file I have to an SD card.

Startup Disk Creator doesn't work ("not enough free space" error -- not true), UNetbootin only works for USB flash drives, and I am also having an issue with using the terminal for this operation.

So, can anybody recommended some software that confirmed works for this.

Very much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257700/how-to-write-a-iso-file-to-an-sd-card?rq=1

Comment: yup `dd` is the way to go if you want to write on the SD card. look at ipse lute's link.

Comment: @Ziazis
The terminal method hasn't been working for me either. I'm not sure why. I'll type in why I've been doing.

1. `sudo umount /dev/sde1`                                                                                               
2. `sudo dd bs=4M if=Win10_1511_2_English_x64.iso                  of=/home/name/Downloads`, whereas `name` is my username

3. I get this error: `dd: failed to open 'Win10_1511_2_English_x64.iso': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hallo  Akman6 please check this :https://www.ridgerun.com/developer/wiki/index.php/How_to_boot_a_board_from_a_SD_card

i guess this will help you.

Comment: The page from your link doesn't appear to exist. It redirects to a company site and the link is not secure (http instead of https). Please add the main steps of the procedure in your answer, and add web links for future/detailed reference.

Comment: Sorry i will provide this soon. My best guess is to work with terminal. But there is enough information about this topic. I used the raspberry forum for this.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257700/how-to-write-a-iso-file-to-an-sd-card    . read this please.

Comment: **Update:**
@Mokum
So, I finally got the terminal method to work for me. I just entered the command, and it's currently acting as if nothing is happening. How do I know when the writing process is finished, and how do I verify if the ISO image was written to the drive correctly?

Comment: @AKMan6 ,as far as i remember you dont get a message when your card is ready. Unplug it safely and put it back in. It should pop up in your file manager.  That should do it.

Comment: @Mokum
Well, I did end up getting a message from the terminal that the writing process had finished. I tried to boot up from the now live SD card, but failed once again. My computer refuses to boot from any live media besides a USB flash drive. Thanks anyway, though. I'll accept your answer just because it's the closest I got to this all working.